# NULL implicit pointer conversion causing ambiguous overload

Tags: c++, null, implicit-conversion, c++03, overload-resolution

Problematic C++03 code:

```cpp
#include <cstddef>
struct Foo {
    explicit Foo(const char *){}
    Foo &operator=(const char *) {return *this;}
    Foo &operator=(char) {return *this;}
};
int main() {
    Foo s("foobar");
    s = NULL;
}
```

Error:

```cpp
In file included from /opt/compiler-explorer/gcc-10.2.0/include/c++/10.2.0/cstddef:50,
                 from <source>:1: <source>: In function 'int main()': <source>:9:9: error: ambiguous overload for 'operator=' (operand types are 'Foo' and 'long int')
    9 |     s = NULL;
      |         ^~~~ <source>:4:10: note: candidate: 'Foo& Foo::operator=(const char*)'
    4 |     Foo &operator=(const char *) {return *this;}
      |          ^~~~~~~~ <source>:5:10: note: candidate: 'Foo& Foo::operator=(char)'
    5 |     Foo &operator=(char) {return *this;}
      |          ^~~~~~~~
```

If I understand correctly, the source of the problem comes from the fact that `NULL` in C++03 can act as both an integer and a pointer. I am also aware that C++11 and later provide `nullptr` to solve this problem. Upgrading to C++11 is not an option for me.

Question: how is this problem solved in practice and how can I keep the ability to provide overloads?

One way is to tell the user not to use `NULL`. Is there a programmatic solution?

Comment: Not sure how you'll get out of this jam, as this was precisely why `nullptr` was introduced. If you're stuck with C++03 you're sort of stuck with this ambiguity. Is the `char` version of `operator=` strictly necessary? Could you add a `clear()` function that handles the `= NULL` case?

Comment: @tadman yes, I can add functions. Could you show an example of what you mean by the `clear()` function? I don't understand how to implement it.

Comment: In practice we don't overload a function in an ambiguous way. To do so is to invoke the "do what I mean" design pattern; tempting, I know, but don't.

Comment: `void clear() { ... }` where that does whatever `operator=(const char*)` does when given `NULL`.

Comment: ``nullptr`` can be backported to C++03 without issues, and it's something that any project that eventually intends to migrate to later Standards would benefit from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A way to achieve it is to use a proxy struct for `char`, which will make `operator=(const char*)` preferrable. Like this:

```
#include <cstddef>

struct MyChar
{
    MyChar(char c) : c(c){}
    operator char() {return c;}
    char c;
};

struct Foo {
    explicit Foo(const char *){}
    Foo &operator=(const char *) {return *this;}
    Foo &operator=(MyChar) {return *this;}
};
int main() {
    Foo s("foobar");
    s = NULL;
    s = 'x';
    s = "foo";
}
```